# Enum value to Enum Object when running query via HQL

Tags: hibernate

When i ran a HQL - i get the enum value as EmployeeStatusEnum[ACTIVE]
The java enum class name is EmployeeStatusEnum with enum values as ACTIVE, INACTIVE, HOLD

Please let me know how to get the enum from the value - EmployeeStatusEnum[ACTIVE] or we need to write a custom string function to get the enum?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your hql and related entity mapping.

Comment: No entity mapping. It is just a direct HQL statement

Comment: [HQL](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql) assume that you have entities model and then you write a HQL query among this model. Maybe we are talking about [native sql query](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql).

Comment: Yes. getting value from native sql query. In such a case how to convert to enum object or how to check with enum

Comment: What database do you use? What type the column has in database?

Comment: SQL Server and the column type is enum